# using sed -i Mac OSX without a backup file

Tags: macos, sed

I found this post: [Variations of sed between OSX and GNU/Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320564/variations-of-sed-between-osx-and-gnu-linux)

[SED without backup file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25486667/sed-without-backup-file)

Which provided the solution for using sed -i on Mac OSX such that it does not create a back file on a search and replace command.

E.g.,
Note the singlequote space singlequote after -i option to specify a zero length extension:

```
sed -i ' ' 's/foo/|bar/g' test.html
```

My problem - this DOES create a backup file for me, and it gives the backup file the same name as my input file, "test.html"

I need to run a search/replace on many files, and I don't want backup files.

Here's my actual command:

```
sed -i ' ' "s|research/projects/vertebrategenome/havana/|science/groups/vertebrate-annotation|g" test2.html
```

Where I get a backup file called "test2.html"

Comment: if you have a space char between the two `'` chars, remove the space and just use `-i ''` . ALSO how do you know you have a backup file, edit your Q to include output for `ls -ls firstFileInDir*` . Good luck.

Comment: @cath, mind marking the answer as accepted answer if it worked for you?  Thanks

Comment: @atifm - thank you! I clicked the green check, I assume that is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the mac, you get the BSD version of sed.  It required to include a null string as an argument to -i.  Note, on linux, it is happy to accept the -i with no extension.

On Linux:

```
sed -i 's|StringToReplace|ReplacedString|'
```

on MacOSX/*BSD

```
sed -i '' 's|StringToReplace|ReplacedString|'
```

Note, you want a nullstring ('') not a blank(' ').

Answer (score 4):

The best way I have found to have the same script work on both Linux and Mac is to:

```
sed -i.bak -e 's/foo/bar/' -- ${TARGET}
rm ${TARGET}.bak
```

Comment: What's the `.bak` mean on the `-i` flag?

Comment: Answering my own comment above. The man-page of `sed` on MacOS doesn't do a good job of explaining it, but `sed -i` will assume that "backups" of the modified files should be created. These backups will have the same name as the original file, but with a specified extension. This extension is specified after the `-i`. If no backup file is needed, an empty string should be specified like the following: `sed -i '' -e 's/foo/bar/g' test.txt`.