I want to change all matching tmp_[1] to tmp__1_ using sed in a file
I want to change all matching tmp_[1] to tmp__1_ using sed in a file. The number 1 can be any number of digits and [ has to be changed to - using sed all occurrences have to be changed
tmp_[1] to tmp__1_ using sed in a file and tmp_[22] to tmp__22_

We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

sed -E 's/tmp[(\d+)]/tmp_(\1)_/g' file.txt which is not working

@BaneshwarShanbhag \d is not recognised as a regular expression extension in sed, whereas [[:digit:]] is a valid character class.

Using sed
$ sed -E ':a;s/(tmp[^ ]*)[][]/\1_/;ta' input_file
tmp__22_
tmp__1_


consider input like [tmp]abc or [also:tmp_[1]] or tmp_[a][b][c]

\d does not mean digit in the regular expression flavours used by sed.
You can use [0-9] or [[:digit:]]:
sed -E 's/(tmp_)\[([0-9]+)]/\1_\2_/g'

(backslash before [ is required to match it literally; backslash before ] is optional.)

I am seeing error if I try to do this inline ie sed -iE, sed -iE 's/(tmp)[([0-9]+)]./\1_\2__/g' tmp.txt
sed: -e expression #1, char 31: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS .Please let me know how to do this using perl -iE.

backslash before [ is required to match it literally

I am seeing the same error even after adding the backslash before [.
sed -iE 's/(tmp)[([0-9]+)]./\1_\2__/g' tmp.txt sed: -e expression #1, char 29: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS

I see no difference between that command and the one in your first comment. Observe that my code has a single backslash on the left side, not one before every [.

sed -E works but sed -iE doesnt work and gives the above error.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906892/using-sed-i-mac-osx-without-a-backup-file / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247068/sed-command-with-i-option-failing-on-mac-but-works-on-linux / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320564/sed-i-command-for-in-place-editing-to-work-with-both-gnu-sed-and-bsd-osx / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-bsd-and-linux
